# PIG LATIN REGEX_EXTRACT:

Tags: regex, apache-pig, extract, latin

I am trying to use regex_extract to get everything after the # from a tweet. I am using this code, but I keep getting nothing, no error, just empty space where I should get the extract from the tweet, what am I doing wrong?

```
grunt> a = load '/user/manuelrivera11828510/lab/pig/full_text.txt' AS (id:chararray, ts:chararray, location:chararray, lat:float, lon:float, 
tweet:chararray);

grunt> b = foreach a generate id, ts, (lat, lon) as location, REGEX_EXTRACT(tweet, '(.*)#(\\s{8})([:| ])(.*)',2) as hash;
```

This is what I am getting (an example):

```
(USER_8f811b71,2010-03-06T16:12:59,(40.722733,-73.5367),)
```

Thank you,

Comment: hi. the delimiter was comma(,)

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=\\#).*` should get you what you are looking for. ?<= is positive lookbehind followed by \ which is for escaping #.Finally .* will match everything in front of #

```
a = load '/user/manuelrivera11828510/lab/pig/full_text.txt' AS (id:chararray, ts:chararray, location:chararray, lat:float, lon:float, tweet:chararray);
b = foreach a generate id, ts, (lat, lon) as location, REGEX_EXTRACT(tweet, '(?<=\#).*',1) as hash;`
```

See below, the regex matches "geteverything in fron of hash"

[image]